How to use Microsoft.Data.SqlClient with Microsoft.Aspnet.identity.EntityFramework?
I have an ASP.NET MVC web project on .NET 4.8 that uses Azure SQL to host users (aspnetusers) and the Microsoft.Aspnet.identity.EntityFramework is used to work with those tables.
I have a new requirement to use azure managed identity, so I need to replace System.Data.SqlClient to Microsoft.Data.SqlClient and change the connection string. This works normal in my other project but in this case, the Microsoft.Aspnet.identity.EntityFramework references System.Data.SqlClient, I tried many ways and could not get it to work.
The following code is one of suggested way from searching on web and I still get error
public class SetMicrosoftDataSqlClient : DbConfiguration
{
    public SetMicrosoftDataSqlClient()
    {
        SetProviderServices("System.Data.SqlClient", SqlProviderServices.Instance);
    }   
}

[DbConfigurationType(typeof(SetMicrosoftDataSqlClient))]
public class ApplicationIdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationIdentityDbContext(string connectionString) : base(new Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString), false) {

        DbConfiguration.SetConfiguration(new SetMicrosoftDataSqlClient());
    }              

    public static ApplicationIdentityDbContext Create()
    {
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IdentityDb"].ConnectionString;
        return new ApplicationIdentityDbContext(connectionString);
    }
}

Errors:
Server Error in '/' Application.

Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' to type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' to type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'.

Source Error:

Line 2217:  
Line 2218:            // Is this email in our system?  
Line 2219:            user = await this.FindByEmailAsync(email);  
Line 2220:  
Line 2221:            if (user == null)  

Source File: F:\Repos\SBMP\WebApp\SBMP\Infrastructure\ApplicationUserManager.cs    Line: 2219 

Stack Trace:

   [InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' to type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'.]  
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.set_DbConnection(DbConnection value) +26  
   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.set_Connection(DbConnection value) +9  
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.set_DbConnection(DbConnection value) +9  
   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.set_Connection(DbConnection value) +9  
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Utils.CommandHelper.SetStoreProviderCommandState(EntityCommand entityCommand, EntityTransaction entityTransaction, DbCommand storeProviderCommand) +62  
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.PrepareEntityCommandBeforeExecution(EntityCommand entityCommand) +155  
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior) +25  
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute(ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues) +735  
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<>c__DisplayClass41_0.<GetResults>b__1() +85  
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction(Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess) +292  
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<>c__DisplayClass41_0.<GetResults>b__0() +132  
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +189  
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) +212  
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__31_0() +11  
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext() +39  
   System.Linq.Enumerable.Single(IEnumerable`1 source) +113
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.<>c__14`1.<GetElementFunction>b__14_3(IEnumerable`1 sequence) +7  
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle(IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot) +25  
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) +59  
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) +70  
   System.Linq.Queryable.Count(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate) +234  
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.History.HistoryRepository.QueryExists(String contextKey) +597  
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.History.HistoryRepository.Exists(String contextKey) +39  
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.History.HistoryRepository.GetLastModel(String& migrationId, String& productVersion, String contextKey) +58  
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.QueryForModel(DatabaseExistenceState existenceState) +39  
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.ModelCompatibilityChecker.CompatibleWithModel(InternalContext internalContext, ModelHashCalculator modelHashCalculator, Boolean throwIfNoMetadata, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState) +52  
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CompatibleWithModel(Boolean throwIfNoMetadata, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState) +54  
   System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context) +109  
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.<>c__DisplayClass66_0`1.<CreateInitializationAction>b__0() +76  
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) +60  
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization() +372
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.<>c.<InitializeDatabase>b__58_0(InternalContext c) +9
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input) +129
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action) +196
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase() +86
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize() +30
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +16
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +53
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext() +15
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider() +38
   System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate, CancellationToken cancellationToken) +138
   System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate) +145
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.<GetUserAggregateAsync>d__67.MoveNext() +402
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +102
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +64
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +29
   SBMP.Infrastructure.<MLSAuthenticateAsync>d__22.MoveNext() in F:\Repos\SBMP\WebApp\SBMP\Infrastructure\ApplicationUserManager.cs:2219
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +102
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +64
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +29
   SBMP.Controllers.<Index>d__2.MoveNext() in F:\Repos\SBMP\WebApp\SBMP\Controllers\LoginController.cs:64
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +102
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +64
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +17
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__0() +58
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_2.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__2() +228
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_5.<BeginInvokeAction>b__4() +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +91
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +11
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecute>b__151_2(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +577
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +132
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +163


"I need to replace System.Data.SqlClient to Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" but then this line:  SetProviderServices("System.Data.SqlClient", SqlProviderServices.Instance); seems to do the complete opposite. Shouldn't it be SetProviderServices("Microsoft.Data.SqlClient", SqlProviderServices.Instance);?

I tried both :) same results
